# JQuery - get property of selected option, on change event

Tags: jquery, select, prop

I have two `<select>` elements. the second is populated through ajax when the first  is changed.
So far so good.
The populated content is the inner html content of the element.

```
<select id="PaymentContractId">
  <!-- dynamic content start -->
  <option title="400" value="12">XXX Street,326</option>
  <option title="500" value="67">YYY Street, 444</option>
  <!-- dynamic content end -->
</select>
```

The JQuery code is:

```
  $("#PaymentContractId").on('change', function(eve) {
    console.log($("option:selected").prop("title"));
    // console.log($("#PaymentContractId option:selected").prop("title")); 
    // this also failed
  });
```

The code returns empty strings. any idea why (or how to do it)?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/xU39Z/

Comment: Apparently, the problem was (why?) a title attribute that the parent `<select>` had. i removed it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be because there are other selects in the page, you need to target the options within the current select element

```
  $("#PaymentContractId").on('change', function(eve) {
    console.log($(this).find("option:selected").prop("title"));
  });
```

Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3rh4a/) - [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3rh4a/4/)